# Rest controller for users with different role

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am making a stadium management software. I want to create a rest API in this project. I am using Spring boot, Spring MVC. I have some resources which are 'Player, Coach, Storekeeper, Helper, Guard'. I have created a Controller for each resource. Now the problem is that every resource has some common fields like name field, address field, phone and email fields, and many more. In the database, I have a common base entity named 'Person'. I have created these entities by JPA Table per Concrete class inheritance strategy. Now in each controller, I have a method to update these duplicate fields and some other duplicate tasks like disabling accounts. I want a suggestion on how to remove this duplicacy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use @MappedSuperclass. You can create a class Person with all common fields and annotate with @MappedSuperclass. This class will have its own getters setters. So, you can extend other classes like coach etc. to this super class. This, will save your code to define fields and getters/setters in each class.

However, you will still have to get/set them in your logic. Advantage of this is - your entities are loosely coupled. you can have different logic for every entity for same field. Like - You want to mandate coach to have mobile number. But student may or may not have mobile no.

But, if you want to remove get/set logic from everywhere, and have it centralised, I am not sure if that can be achieved. Even if you use table joins, get/set has to be from corresponding class.